# why the queries run by a specific user are slow?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, trace, query-cache

[Here you can see how to save the contents of the default trace into a table.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2695/maintaining-sql-server-default-trace-historical-events-for-analysis-and-reporting/)

I have been saving the contents of the default trance into a table in my `DBA` database.

The table is called `[DBA].[dbo].[DefaultTrace_History]`.

when I query the trace table to find out about the user `mycompany\myuser`, some his queries seem to be running slow.

```
SELECT [TextData]
      ,[Database]='my database' --db_name([DatabaseID])
      ,[HostName]='my server'
      ,[ApplicationName]
      ,[LoginName]='mycompany\myuser'
      --,[SPID]
      ,[StartTime]=MAX([StartTime])
      --,[EndTime]
      --,[Duration]
      --,[ObjectID]
      --,[ObjectType]
      --,[IndexID]
      ,[EventClass]
      ,[EventClass-Name]=te.name
      --,[FileName]
      --,[RowCounts]
      --,[IsSystem]
      ,[SqlHandle]
  FROM [DBA].[dbo].[DefaultTrace_History] dth
  inner join sys.trace_events te
          on dth.EventClass = te.trace_event_id
  where LoginName = 'mycompany\myuser'
  GROUP BY
       [TextData]
      ,[DatabaseID]
      ,[HostName]
      ,[ApplicationName]
      ,[LoginName]
      --,[SPID]
      --,[StartTime]=MAX([StartTime])
      --,[EndTime]
      --,[Duration]
      --,[ObjectID]
      --,[ObjectType]
      --,[IndexID]
      ,[EventClass]
      ,te.name
      --,[FileName]
      --,[RowCounts]
      --,[IsSystem]
      ,[SqlHandle]
  order by StartTime desc
```

I get the following EvenClasses, that I am concerned about:

1. Sort Warnings
2. Missing Join Predicate
3. Missing Column Statistics
4. Hash Warning

as you can see on the picture below:

[image]

**Missing Join Predicate**

[the Missing Join Predicate has been discussed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35082/what-exactly-does-no-join-predicate-mean-in-sql-server) and [Here too](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34193/should-i-be-alarmed-by-this-no-join-predicate-warning).

**Missing Column Statistics**

I have fixed it, or at least got rid of the warning by simply running

```
sp_updatestats
```

(although the database in question has auto-create stats on) Otherwise [it has been discussed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102467/warning-for-missing-statistics-in-execution-plan/151613#151613) and [scripting statistics here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151139/22336)

**Sort Warning**

[The sort warning has been discussed here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65757/22336) which includes a script to find the stored procedures with sort warnings plus the below by Paul White:

> Cached plans are always pre-execution (estimated) plans. Sort warnings
>   are only present in post-execution (actual) plans. Collecting data
>   using Extended Events or Event Notifications is indeed the way to go.

**Hash Warning**

[The Hash Warning and Sort warnings too have been discussed here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47509/22336)
where Paul
and again by Paul White:

> you can monitor the spills using Extended Events or Profiler Sort
>   Warnings and Hash Warnings. Memory is reserved for sorts and hashes
>   based on cardinality estimates before execution starts, and cannot be
>   increased during execution regardless of how much spare memory your
>   SQL Server may have. Accurate row count estimates are therefore
>   crucial for any execution plan that involves workspace memory
>   consuming operations.
>
> Your query is also parameterized. You should consider adding OPTION
>   (RECOMPILE) to the query if different parameter values affect the
>   query plan. You should probably consider using it anyway, so the
>   optimizer can see the value of @Param1 at compilation time. If nothing
>   else, this may help the optimizer produce a more reasonable estimate
>   for the index seek shown above, given that the table is very large,
>   and partitioned. It may also enable static partition elimination.
>
> Try the query again with a temporary table instead of the table
>   variable and OPTION (RECOMPILE).

**QUESTION:**

The default trace does not give me the sql statements (either ad hoc or stored procedures) that have been run by `mycompany\myuser` in order to get those `warnings` or better saying `EvenClasses`.

> How can I find out what statements were executed by `mycompany\myuser`
>   in order to get those `warnings` or better saying `EvenClasses`?

I have thought about maybe adding `SQL:BatchCompleted` to the default trace, if at all possible, but then I get concerned about the extra cost on the default trace.

Another idea that came from he comments by `Paul White` is using `Extended Events`, but would I be able to link both (the default trace with the tracks of `mycompany\myuser` and the `Extended Events data`?

Comment: With Extended Events, you can add global fields when the event is captured, including `sql_text` and `nt_username`.

Comment: Sounds like you should turn on the Query Store. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store

Comment: >>>I have thought about maybe adding SQL:BatchCompleted to the default trace, if at all possible<<< You cannot add nothing to the default trace